Flutter - Android emulator - Android Studio - how can I see the output?
I have a flutter project which I am running through Android Studio via an Emulator. I can see the app running on the emulator, but I cannot see any output printed somewhere on Android Studio.. I have various prints in my app so I should be seeing some output.. How can I see this output on Android Studio?

If you launched it through the Run command, you should see it in the Run panel below (icon: rightward arrow). But you can also use the integrated Logcat panel (icon: cat).

Logs are printed in Logcat. It is usually open but you can open it with:
Select View > Tool Windows > Logcat from the menu bar.
You can also then filter by your package name.

You can check the toolbar in android studio and look for 'View -> Tool Windows -> Run,' or use 'Command + 4' on Mac, or 'Alt + 4' on Windows

ctrl+shift+` click at output between debug console and problems
